# How to create a user and get the newly created ID with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am new to the ASP.NET Identity framework and am trying to do some things that I used to do in the older FormsAuthentication framework.

What I want to do is allow an administrative user to create a new user using the existing Register view (or similar) from within the app.  Once this is complete, I would like to relationally associate that user (possibly using the ID that is generated) to other areas of the system.

How do I get access to the ID that is generated when calling UserManager.CreateAsync()?

EDIT: I am wanting existing users with "administrative" roles to create users from within the system in a User Management area.  The answers below so far have explained how to get the ID for the "current" user which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Using the `IdentityUser` or using a class that inherits from `IdentityUser`, makes the model having an `UserId` attribute. Using following code, passing the user to the method, will fill up the Id.

```
var user = model.GetUser();
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

if (result.Succeeded)
    result = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");
```

The `model.GetUser()` returns an object of the `ApplicationUser` or `IdentityUser`

```
public ApplicationUser GetUser()
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser
    {
        UserName = UserName,
        FirstName = FirstName,
        LastName = LastName,
        Email = Email,
        ...
    };

    return user;
}
```

Comment: I dont see where I get the ID of the user that was just created.  Does the CreateAsync() method populate the 'user' parameter?

Comment: And it populates the fields of IdentityUser which has the id field.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I was looking for.  A way to get the data of a recently created user when created by another user from within the system.

Answer (score 22):

The accepted answer was not clear to me so I thought I would share this.

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityUser.cs) for the [IdentityUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser(v=vs.108).aspx) class you will find the following.

```
public class IdentityUser : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>, IUser, IUser<string>
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Constructor which creates a new Guid for the Id
    /// </summary>
    public IdentityUser()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    ... code omitted
}
```

As you can see, when creating a new `IdentityUser` instance the constructor generates a new GUID and populates the Id field.

This means if you create a new instance of a derived class such as `ApplicationUser` a new Id will still automatically be generated for you.

So, after you check that the user has been *successfully* added you can safely use the Id in the `ApplicationUser` class for your data association.

Example.

```
var user = new ApplicationUser
{
    UserName = "franko",
    FirstName = "Frank",
    LastName = "Ouimette",
    Email = "franko@emailservice.com"
};

var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

if (result.Succeeded){
    result = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");

    // User added successfully, you can safely use the Id now.
    var id = user.Id;

}
```

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me was something slightly different:

```
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
var user = new ApplicationUser() { Email = "informatyka4444@wp.pl", UserName = "informatyka4444@wp.pl" };
var result = manager.Create(user, "TestPass44!");

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    string newId = user.Id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fernando this solution fits better for my use case (we use email's as username and have more manual control over the user management process)

Answer (score 4):

Some extension methods have been added to the Identity framework, including this one:

```
public static string GetUserId(this IIdentity identity);
```

After performing the sign-in, you should be able to retrieve the ID easily enough:

```
await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
var id = this.User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

Comment: Wont that give me the ID of the current user?  I want the ID that the current user created when adding another user.

Comment: @FrankO, if the `GetUserId` method takes an `IIdentity` (a user) as a parameter, why wouldn't it give you the ID of *that* user?

Answer (score 1):

This thread is already a few years old, but I encountered this problem and needed to find another solution because I do not use the provided `Guids`, but a standard integer ID, provided by the database (auto-incremented index).

The problem that I had was that if I created the user with `UserManager.CreateAsync`, the user object wasn't updated with the ID. I then created a related object for that user, and since the ID wasn't updated, Entity Framework tried to save the user to the database another time which resulted in a primary key violation.

To solve the problem, I needed to read/update the user object like so:

```
var user = new User
{
    UserName = UserName,
    FirstName = FirstName,
    LastName = LastName,
    Email = Email,
    ...
};

var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

// At this point, the user has been created, but the ID not set

// Read the full user record from the database
user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == user.Email).FirstOrDefault();

// At this point, the user has the correct ID set, we are good to go...
```

Comment: Is your User object inheriting from the IdentityUser?

Comment: No, my User class implements the `IUser<int>` interface.

Comment: Seems odd that the ID is not being populated.  Have you tried inheriting from IdentityUser?

Comment: I agree, it's surprising behaviour. I have made this decision two years ago, but I think I used the `iUser` interface because I use a database-first approach. It allowed me to independently model the user entity in the database. After I imported my data model, I created a partial class for the User entity that inherits the bespoke interface, so that I can plug it into my user manager.

Answer (score -3):

In the event for user created, add:

```
string user = RegisterUser.UserName; or to use later 
Session["user"] = RegisterUser.UserName;
```